# Swift: How to detect when pan gesture is dismissed / cancelled?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom table cell that is swipeable. I'm using this library to inherit from: https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell

In order to prevent 2 cells from being swiped at the same time, I have a global boolean that I just toggle `true / false` when ever something is swiped.

However, I can't find any callbacks for when the user starts a swipe but lets go, which essentially cancels the swipe. Is there a way to do this? I'm looking for a callback similar to `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`, but for when a gesture is dismissed / cancelled.

```
typealias SwipeHandler = () -> ()

class OrderCellManager {
  static var swiping = false
}

class OrderPreparingTableViewCell: MCSwipeTableViewCell {
  override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if (!OrderCellManager.swiping) {
      OrderCellManager.swiping = true
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  func displayOrder(order: AppState.Order, clock: Clock, fDone: @escaping SwipeHandler, fDelete: @escaping SwipeHandler) -> OrderPreparingTableViewCell {
    ..
    self.setSwipeGestureWith(lSwipe, color: Config.ColorSwipeDelete, mode: .exit, state: .state1, completionBlock:currySwipe(f: fDelete))
    self.setSwipeGestureWith(rSwipe, color: Config.ColorSwipeDone, mode: .exit, state: .state3, completionBlock:currySwipe(f: fDone))
    ..
  }

  // MARK: Private

  private func currySwipe(f: @escaping SwipeHandler) -> MCSwipeCompletionBlock {
    return { (a: MCSwipeTableViewCell?, b: MCSwipeTableViewCellState, c: MCSwipeTableViewCellMode) -> () in
      OrderCellManager.swiping = false

      f()
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func pan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .changed: fallthrough
        case .ended:
            // update anything that depends on the pan gesture using translation.x and .y
        case .cancelled:
            //do your thing here
        default: break
        }
    }
```

in your **viewDidLoad** method add this code

```
self.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(
            target: view,action:#selector(MCSwipeTableViewCell.pan(gesture:))
))
```

Comment: do i put this in the controller or in my custom cell class?

Comment: put in the your custom cell. you can move this method to your custom cell.

Comment: hm this covers the existing slide gesture recognizer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended { //code }
```

Comment: where would i put that ?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did this, made available by the table cell pod I'm using:

```
class OrderTableManager {
  static var swiping = false
}

class OrderPreparingTableViewCell: MCSwipeTableViewCell, MCSwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
  override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if !OrderTableManager.swiping {
      OrderTableManager.swiping = true
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  // MARK: Public
  func swipeTableViewCellDidEndSwiping(_ cell: MCSwipeTableViewCell!) {
    OrderTableManager.swiping = false
  }

  func displayOrder(order: AppState.Order, clock: Clock, fDone: @escaping SwipeHandler, fDelete: @escaping SwipeHandler) -> OrderPreparingTableViewCell {
    ...

    self.delegate = self

    ...
  }
```